# Is there any way so that it should not destroy and re-create the subnets while cereating those using count method instead of cretating one by one?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform-provider-aws

I am using terraform to create resources and other thing on aws.

I was creating subnets one by one as following:

```
resource "aws_subnet" "subnet-1" {
  cidr_block        = "192.0.0.0/27"
  availability_zone = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[0]
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.main.id
  tags = {
    Name = var.public_subnet_1_name
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "subnet-2" {
  cidr_block        = "192.0.0.32/27"
  availability_zone = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[1]
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.main.id
  tags = {
    Name = var.public_subnet_2_name
  }
}
```

Now I am creating these subnets using count method as following:

```
variable "subnet_cidr_block" {                                                  
  default = ["192.0.0.0/27" , "192.0.0.32/27"]                 
  type    = list
```

}

```
resource "aws_subnet" "public" {                                                
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.main.id                                           
  count             = length(var.subnet_cidr_block)                             
  cidr_block        = element(var.subnet_cidr_block, count.index)               
  availability_zone = element(data.aws_availability_zones.available.names, count.index)
                                                                               
  tags = {                                                                      
    Name = "${var.env}-public-subnet-${count.index + 1}"                        
  }                                                                             
}
```

After running command for plan using terraform as terraform plan, it gives me plan as earlier subnets will be destroyed and new subnets will be created as:

```
# aws_subnet.public[0] will be created
+ resource "aws_subnet" "public" {
  + arn                             = (known after apply)
  + assign_ipv6_address_on_creation = false
  + availability_zone               = "ap-south-1a"
  + availability_zone_id            = (known after apply)
  + cidr_block                      = "192.0.0.0/27"
  + id                              = (known after apply)
  + ipv6_cidr_block                 = (known after apply)
  + ipv6_cidr_block_association_id  = (known after apply)
  + map_public_ip_on_launch         = false
  + owner_id                        = (known after apply)
  + tags                            = {
      + "Name" = "staging-public-subnet-1"
    }
  + vpc_id                          = "vpc-052108c465bd3a748"
}

# aws_subnet.public[1] will be created
+ resource "aws_subnet" "public" {
  + arn                             = (known after apply)
  + assign_ipv6_address_on_creation = false
  + availability_zone               = "ap-south-1b"
  + availability_zone_id            = (known after apply)
  + cidr_block                      = "192.0.0.32/27"
  + id                              = (known after apply)
  + ipv6_cidr_block                 = (known after apply)
  + ipv6_cidr_block_association_id  = (known after apply)
  + map_public_ip_on_launch         = false
  + owner_id                        = (known after apply)
  + tags                            = {
      + "Name" = "staging-public-subnet-2"
    }
  + vpc_id                          = "vpc-052108c465bd3a748"
}

# aws_subnet.subnet-1 will be destroyed
- resource "aws_subnet" "subnet-1" {
  - arn                             = "arn:aws:ec2:ap-south-1:989263488711:subnet/subnet-08399b7864bcd179e" -> null
  - assign_ipv6_address_on_creation = false -> null
  - availability_zone               = "ap-south-1a" -> null
  - availability_zone_id            = "aps1-az1" -> null
  - cidr_block                      = "192.0.0.0/27" -> null
  - id                              = "subnet-08399b7864bcd179e" -> null
  - map_public_ip_on_launch         = false -> null
  - owner_id                        = "989263488711" -> null
  - tags                            = {
      - "Name" = "staging-public-subnet-1"
    } -> null
  - vpc_id                          = "vpc-052108c465bd3a748" -> null
}

# aws_subnet.subnet-2 will be destroyed
- resource "aws_subnet" "subnet-2" {
  - arn                             = "arn:aws:ec2:ap-south-1:989263488711:subnet/subnet-0131ffa3ea93538f5" -> null
  - assign_ipv6_address_on_creation = false -> null
  - availability_zone               = "ap-south-1b" -> null
  - availability_zone_id            = "aps1-az3" -> null
  - cidr_block                      = "192.0.0.32/27" -> null
  - id                              = "subnet-0131ffa3ea93538f5" -> null
  - map_public_ip_on_launch         = false -> null
  - owner_id                        = "989263488711" -> null
  - tags                            = {
      - "Name" = "staging-public-subnet-2"
    } -> null
  - vpc_id                          = "vpc-052108c465bd3a748" -> null
}
```

As I have changed resource name, so it's destroying and creating subnets again. So there will be impact on my other resources as these subnets have been used in other resources ie it will change subnets id and other database resources will be impacted.

Is there a way so that it should not destroy subnets and re-create?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These will be new resources in Terraform as they are now part of a count array. Notice in the plan the number in the square brackets `aws_subnet.public[1]`

Yes if you apply that plan it will attempt to destroy then build new subnets. I'm not sure if this would succeed in all honesty if you have other resources that are binded to the subnet

If those existing subnets must exist, and you still want to use the count method, the way to achieve this is to use the `terraform state rm` to remove the existing subnets from the statefile (https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/state/rm.html).

Then perform a `terraform import` using your count way of declaring resources https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/import.html